# Energy gap of a Heisenberg model on bipartite lattices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, spin-models

Consider the antiferromagnetic Heisenberg model on some "graph" where each vertex corresponds to a spin-1/2 and the edges represent interaction between the vertices, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle \in E} \hat{S}_i \cdot \hat{S}_j ~,
\end{equation}

for a graph $G=(V,E)$.
From intuition coming from the square lattice case ($G=\mathbb{Z}^2$), I think it is well-established that the first excitation above the ground state corresponds to some kind of a magnon and therefore has a power-law ~$O(1/\mathrm{poly}(N))$ decaying energy gap in terms of the system size $N=|V|$.

**Question** :
Can anyone give me a reference for a rigorous proof of this result for general bipartite graphs $G$, or even in restricted cases such as when $G$ corresponds to a complete bipartite graph (Lieb-Mattis model)?

I found that in the "Koma-Tasaki" theorem, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02188685, and also in more recent works (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-018-2193-8 ) the authors rigorously prove the structure of the "Tower of states" in the AFM Heisenberg model, but I can only find them *upper* bounding the energy gap with $O(1/N)$. I would like to know if the energy gap could be *lower* bounded by some $O(1/\mathrm{poly}(N))$. Or is this simply an open problem for general bipartite graphs?

Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just want to note that the theorems you cited all assume the ground state has long-range order. So it is not as strong as what you want.

Comment: Thank you @MengCheng for your comment! You're right. I was somehow imagining that on a bipartite lattice, the Neel order would be the only LRO possible or else it will not have any, and was thinking that since the Neel order allows the collective "gapless" behavior of Magnons, not having LRO should make it easier to prove (inverse-polynomial) gappedness. But I guess at the moment I don't even know if that's actually true.